# how to access the variable to the page without using GET and POST methods and without using header function?

Tags: php

Below are two files `first.php` and `second.php` I want to access the `$name` variable in the second file.
 I used global but it just access values inside the file. I do not want to use `POST` and `GET` method because I used `POST` already for redirecting to `home.php`

```
first.php
 <?php
 $name = 'New York';
 ?>

  second.php
 <?php
  // Access variable here from the above first.php file 
 ?>
```

Comment: Use `include 'first.php';` in `second.php`?

Comment: Not enough context. So you want a variable to appear out of thin air? But it had to have a value at some point? What's it for? When is it first construed? What type of value? What about sessions or environment variables, or getting it from a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## INCLUDE

**first.php**

```
$name = "New York";
```

**second.php**

```
include "path/to/first.php";
echo $name; //echo "New York"
```

Here is the manual for [PHP: Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

---

### SESSIONS

If you don't want everything from first.php on second.php, you should use sessions.

**first.php**

```
session_start(); //start sessions, so you can use session variables
$_SESSION['name'] = "New York"; //set session variable called "name" to "New York"
```

**second.php**

```
session_start(); //start session so you can use session variables
echo $_SESSION['name']; //echo "New York"
```

Session variables work  basically the same as regular variables, but you access them like an array. You have to start the session on every page to access them. I usually just start sessions in my header file so it's always included.

[More info about PHP sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

---

### COOKIES

You could also use cookies, though I recommend using SESSIONS instead in most cases. Cookies are good for when that variable needs to last through multiple log in sessions or for a really long time, I usually use these for users settings themes in my application and such things that don't change often.

**first.php**

```
$name = "New York"; //set variable
setcookie("name", $name, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); //set cookie that expires in 1 day
```

**seconds.php**

```
echo $_COOKIE['name']; //echo New York
```

[More information on cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: first.php have too many functions so I don't think including files will be safer

Comment: @ashok I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $_SESSION variable.

```
<?php //first.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'New York';
?>
<?php //second.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Try to use explanation text / rationale.

Comment: Thank's mario! In next time I'll explain then

Answer (score 0):

The best and safe way so far is using `include_once()`. If you want to include many files then you may use `__autoload()` **(if it is object orient approach)**.

[Check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$_REQUEST['var'];
```

This adapt with both post and get. Doesn't Metter what you are using. 
Or with `include 'file.php'`
Or with `setcookie('name', 'value'); $_COOKIE['name'];`
Or with session storage